# Custom Heroku database backup

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am using the PG Backups add-on on my Heroku app, but I want to schedule more database backups and upload them to my own AWS S3 account.

How can I do this from a rake task? I have tried using the `pg_dump` command, but it is not available on the heroku server.

I also tried using `heroku pgbackups:capture` so I could get the latest URL and then upload that, but the `heroku` command is also not available on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Install `pg_dump` or the `heroku` tools on the EC2 server you're using to push data to S3 from. You can use `pg_dump` to connect remotely to the Heroku box over an SSL-protected PostgreSQL database connection or you can use the `heroku` commands to do it.